# No module named PIP || PIP command not working (PIP 3.7)

Tags: python, pip

I just download python zip latest version and already installed pip and (wheel etc..)
I cannot run pip commands. CMD saids "No module named PIP"

I have run DIR command in scripts and there's pip inside

```
S:\{ Installed }\Phyton\Scripts>dir

 Volume in drive S is Software

 Volume Serial Number is 1488-3DE4

 Directory of S:\{ Installed }\Phyton\Scripts

06/03/2019  05:41 PM    <DIR>          .
06/03/2019  05:41 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/03/2019  05:41 PM           102,775 easy_install-3.7.exe
06/03/2019  05:41 PM           102,775 easy_install.exe
06/03/2019  05:41 PM           102,757 pip.exe
06/03/2019  05:41 PM           102,757 pip3.7.exe
06/03/2019  05:41 PM           102,757 pip3.exe
06/03/2019  05:41 PM           102,753 wheel.exe
               6 File(s)        616,574 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  40,247,717,888 bytes free
```

Then, I try run these commands still have same output :

```
pip install –upgrade esptool || 
pip install esptool
```

Comment: It is probably a PATH issue. Try to add the `S:\{ Installed }\Phyton\Scripts` to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pip installed but you need to have them available in your system path. From **System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variable**  you will need to set your python DLLs, Lib and binary as follows (mine is set as the following):

```
PYTHON_HOME C:\Program Files\Python37\     System
Path        %PYTHON_HOME%\                 System or User
Path        %PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts\         System or User
```

Also, make sure your Pythonpath is set as follows:

```
PythonPath  C:\Program Files\Python37
            C:\Program Files\Python37\DLLs
            C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib
```

You may need to Sign out and then Sign in for this to take effect.